# Page layout messed up eventhough copied from another page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I ran into a strange problem. That is I made my page "http://chatime.com/m/full/goodtea.html" and made three more copies of the same page. I named each page goodtea2, goodtea3, goodtea4.

When I linked them together, the copied pages shown weirdly. I checked many times and can't figure out what the problem seems to be.

Could any one help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Load jquery before loading jquery mobile in head.

Comment: @Omar, it doesn't help =(

Comment: Jquery mobile uses ajax to load pages, if you to fix your issue, add `rel=external` to your links tags. This will load pages normally without using ajax. Read more about it http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Comment: Welcome. What are you using JQM for if I may ask?

Comment: I guess currently none of the pages require JQM to be loaded. I set it up initially to test around the features of building a mobile site, but then the client requires too much styling, so I went back to play around with what I know best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are having a UTF-8 encoding issue. Make sure your HTML editor is saving the files in UTF-8 without BOM and specify the following tag in the upper section of your HTML files:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> // <- important
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey MonkeyZeus, thanks for the quick reply. I followed your advice to defined DOCTYPE and added charset UTF-8, yet the problem is still present.

Comment: It appears to have some page loader loading the requested page which is very weird. I know I copied codes from here and there, but the link is just a plain <a href=""></a>...